# How do I get my list to stay centered at the bottom of the page even when I adjust window size?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylelogin.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="../designpage/design.html">
      <ul>
        <div>
        <li><input id = "email" type="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
        </li>
        <li><input id = "email" type="password" placeholder="Enter password" required></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="Submit"></li>
      </div>
      </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scriptlogin.js" defer>
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  margin: 50px;
}

#leftlist {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  bottom: 40%;
}

#rightlist {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 40%;
}

#bottomlist {
  position: absolute;
  right:25%;
  bottom: 10%;
}

#bottomlist li {
  display: inline;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

The element with id bottomlist (also, coincidentally, it's the list at the bottom of the screen) comes out pretty garbled the smaller I make the window left-to-right.

Also, do you have any tips for making the "Sign in Using Different Username" text break into two lines that stick together as a single element as I adjust window size left-to-right? I tried putting the list element in a dif and adding a <br> halfway through the text, but the formatting showed up really weird.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I horizontally center an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-can-i-horizontally-center-an-element)